# How to see the rule, when error: didn't match pod anti-affinity rules

Tags: kubernetes, cilium

I am getting - when installing [Cilium](https://cilium.io):

```
Warning  FailedScheduling  4m21s (x17 over 84m)  default-scheduler  0/1 nodes are available: 1 node(s) didn't match pod anti-affinity rules. preemption: 0/1 nodes are available: 1 node(s) didn't match pod anti-affinity rules.
```

How can I see the rule and can I change it?

If I do `kubectl describe node`, id do not have anyy `nodeAffinity` settings. And the Node has `Taints:<none>`

Comment: Affinities are defined on the pod (probably via deployment/statefulset/daemonset). Do a kubectl describe pod

Comment: Thanks, the strange thing is that there is no nodeAffinity when describing the pod?

Comment: Sorry, my bad. You need to get the pods as yaml to see it: `kubectl get pod <name> -o yaml`. There you'll find `spec.affinity`.

Answer (score 1):

Run `$ kubectl get pods` , it shows Pending status. (`kubectl get pods -o wide`)

To describe the pod run `$ kubectl describe pod POD_NAME`, it shows a warning as part of events, if not works, try as suggested by @ **Chris** run `kubectl get pod <name> -o yaml`. There you'll find `spec.affinity`.

After identifying which anti-affinity rules triggers the warning. You can choose to

> either rectify the rule or make some changes in the cluster to support
> the rule

**For example :** let's take a case, try to deploy 4 replicas of Ngnix deployment with **podAntiAffinity** rule in a 3 Node cluster. Here the last replica cannot be scheduled because no available Nodes left.

> You can choose to reduce the number of replicas, increase the number
> of Nodes, adjust the rule to use soft/preference requirements or
> remove the **podAntiAffinity** rule.